# Why did Voldemort leave the ministry temporarily the first time?

Tags: plot-explanation, harry-potter, the-order-of-the-phoenix

I've seen a lot of questions about "Why did Voldemort leave the ministry when the minister and Aurors arrived," but I just rewatched *Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix* and saw that he first left before any of them arrived, and then telepathically got into Harry's mind and then reappeared.

Why did he leave the first time?

Answer (score 4):

He wanted to get into Harry's mind in order to torture or probably kill him. But since Dumbledore was there who was he fighting with, he couldn't do it while being physically present in the ministry. So, he wanted to be in a safe place before possessing Harry.

Therefore, he disapparated to someplace safe for the first time to possess Harry.